# Factory Optimization

Tags: optimization

First I feel like a disclaimer here is needed that this is NOT a homework problem but I am going to ask the question in something that looks like one.  I don't know how to ask my question any other way.

Imagine you have a factory.  The factory produces widgets in the following form:

\begin{aligned}
W &= W_{ps}t \\
W_{ps} &= P(N_p)+R(M_R) \\
\end{aligned}

where $W$ denotes the widgets built and banked, $W_{ps}$ denotes the widgets-per-second built by the factory, $P$ denotes the production of each human worker (in WPS), $N_p$ denotes the number of human workers, $R$ denotes the production of each robot (in WPS), and finally $M_R$ denotes the number of robotic workers.

Now suppose I can use the banked widgets to hire more human workers or robotic workers (we'll just buy with widgets because $Widgets \propto Money$).  At any instant if I have enough widgets to make a hire I can.  I can also bank my widgets to buy a robotic worker (which for the sake of argument produces widgets faster).  In addition the cost to hire humans or buy robots obey the functions

\begin{aligned}
CP(N_p) &= CP_o+f(N_p) \\
CR(M_R) &= CR_o+g(M_R) \\
\end{aligned}

I need to somehow build this purchasing into the first equation given but I don't know how to do that at this moment.

I don't know how to go about optimizing this factory.  Say I want to reach $x$ $W_{ps}$ the fastest.  I am trying to optimize the time to a given $W_{ps}$ value.  At every instant I have a decision to make.  I have to see if I have enough widgets to do anything, if I do I have to decide if it's better to buy a human or wait for a robot.  I don't know how to model this discrete decision making.

Comment: You are right, it does sound like homework. Maybe it would help if you shared how you thought of the question.

Comment: @Adam Have you ever play cookie clicker?  If you haven't don't do it.  But I often compete with friends on the fastest build to a score and I want to optimize my build.

Comment: You can also probably tell that I made this up by my inability to write down proper governing equations.  I don't know how to model this decision making.